# No result defined for action com.hussi.action.LoginAction and result SUCCESS

Tags: java, jsp, configuration, struts2

I am learning struts 2 
here is my web.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
  <display-name>HussiStruts1</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
  <filter>
    <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter</filter-class>
  </filter>
  <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </filter-mapping>
</web-app>
```

here is my struts.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC
   "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.3//EN"
   "http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.3.dtd">
<struts>
    <package name="default" extends="struts-default">
        <action name="login" class="com.hussi.action.LoginAction">
            <result name="SUCCESS">/success.jsp</result>
            <result name="failure">/failure.jsp</result>
        </action>
        <action name="failure" class="com.hussi.action.LoginAction"></action>
    </package>
</struts>
```

here is my action class

```
package com.hussi.action;

public class LoginAction 
{
    public String execute()
    {
        System.out.println("Action : Login Action === Method : execute");
        return "SUCCESS";
    }

}
```

when I am executing the project it goes to index.jsp as its a welcome page

but when I hit the URL : `http://localhost:8080/HussiStruts1/login.action`

it gives error

> **No result defined for action com.hussi.action.LoginAction and result SUCCESS**

also the line in the action class is being printed , which means , action class is reached , its the result not being able to be found ,

I have "web" named as my course folder
and in my struts.xml i have tried

```xml
<result name="SUCCESS">/success.jsp</result>
<result name="SUCCESS">success.jsp</result>
<result name="SUCCESS">web/success.jsp</result>
<result name="SUCCESS">/web/success.jsp</result>
<result name="SUCCESS">./web/success.jsp</result>
```

neither seems to work

here is the whole log

```
Action : Login Action === Method : execute
Nov 30, 2015 12:03:16 AM com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.logging.commons.CommonsLogger warn
WARNING: Could not find action or result
No result defined for action com.hussi.action.LoginAction and result SUCCESS
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.executeResult(DefaultActionInvocation.java:363)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:265)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.DefaultWorkflowInterceptor.doIntercept(DefaultWorkflowInterceptor.java:163)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:87)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:236)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.validator.ValidationInterceptor.doIntercept(ValidationInterceptor.java:249)
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.validation.AnnotationValidationInterceptor.doIntercept(AnnotationValidationInterceptor.java:68)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:87)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:236)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ConversionErrorInterceptor.intercept(ConversionErrorInterceptor.java:122)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:236)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:195)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:87)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:236)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:195)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:87)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:236)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.StaticParametersInterceptor.intercept(StaticParametersInterceptor.java:148)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:236)
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.CheckboxInterceptor.intercept(CheckboxInterceptor.java:93)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:236)
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.FileUploadInterceptor.intercept(FileUploadInterceptor.java:235)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:236)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ModelDrivenInterceptor.intercept(ModelDrivenInterceptor.java:89)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:236)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ScopedModelDrivenInterceptor.intercept(ScopedModelDrivenInterceptor.java:128)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:236)
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.ProfilingActivationInterceptor.intercept(ProfilingActivationInterceptor.java:104)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:236)
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.debugging.DebuggingInterceptor.intercept(DebuggingInterceptor.java:267)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:236)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ChainingInterceptor.intercept(ChainingInterceptor.java:126)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:236)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.PrepareInterceptor.doIntercept(PrepareInterceptor.java:138)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:87)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:236)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.I18nInterceptor.intercept(I18nInterceptor.java:148)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:236)
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.ServletConfigInterceptor.intercept(ServletConfigInterceptor.java:164)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:236)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.AliasInterceptor.intercept(AliasInterceptor.java:128)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:236)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ExceptionMappingInterceptor.intercept(ExceptionMappingInterceptor.java:176)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:236)
    at org.apache.struts2.impl.StrutsActionProxy.execute(StrutsActionProxy.java:52)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.serviceAction(Dispatcher.java:468)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.ExecuteOperations.executeAction(ExecuteOperations.java:77)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.doFilter(StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.java:76)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:217)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:518)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1091)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:673)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1500)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1456)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

any suggestion ??

success.jsp

```xml
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>success</title>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: please add the code of your `success.jsp`

Comment: I think you have a problem with your success.jsp, because in my case it's work without problem

Comment: give me a list of jars you are using

Comment: @MouradBENKDOUR : success.jsp added

Comment: Please check the list of my jars in my answer below

Comment: Try to write the URL like this: http://localhost:8080/HussiStruts1/login

Answer (score 0):

- Maybe you should to add more jar in your library, for me I created a struts2 library which include  those jars:

[image]

[image]

- Maybe also you should add struts 2 Deploy path in Web Deployment Assembly in Eclipse like in this picture :
  [image]

Comment: sorry it was not formatted , but I did try that already , any other possibility >>

Answer (score 0):

> No result defined for action com.hussi.action.LoginAction and result SUCCESS

means that struts can't find a result `<result name="SUCCESS">` for the login action in your `struts.xml`.

In the code you provided the result is defined, so things you might check:

- have you actually saved both files (the action class and struts.xml)
- when you deploy your .war are any old files left behind - try cleaning the project (and the deploy directory of the server)
- maybe the string "SUCCESS" (either in the action or xml) contains some unprintable character (so that they look the same but are actually different)

Answer (score 0):

The error is in your non-standard naming of the `SUCCESS` result, an in the lack of its definition in the second action.

When your action `extends ActionSupport` or `implements Action`, you're able to return the default results by the appropriate constant, eg. `SUCCESS`, `ERROR`, `INPUT`, `NONE`, etc.

The `SUCCESS` constant is mapped to the `"success"` String, that is **lowercase**.

You are instead manually returning the String `"SUCCESS"`, that is **uppercase**, mapping it both in the struts.xml and in the action; it works, but it's definitely a bad practice:

```xml
<action name="login" class="com.hussi.action.LoginAction">
    <result name="SUCCESS">/success.jsp</result>
    <result name="failure">/failure.jsp</result>
</action>
```

Then you are mapping a second action to the same Action class, without defining any result!

```xml
<action name="failure" class="com.hussi.action.LoginAction"></action>
```

This result-less action will call the `execute()` method, that will try to return `"SUCCESS"`, without finding any match.

Then you could duplicate the results for the failure action too

```xml
<action name="login" class="com.hussi.action.LoginAction">
    <result name="SUCCESS">/success.jsp</result>
    <result name="failure">/failure.jsp</result>
</action>
<action name="failure" class="com.hussi.action.LoginAction">
    <result name="SUCCESS">/success.jsp</result>
    <result name="failure">/failure.jsp</result>
</action>
```

but neither this is a best practice; if you need to redirect to the login action in case of failure, **simply use the `redirectAction` result**, with something (that in the following example would imply a method `foo()` returning `SUCCESS`, or `"success"`) like:

```xml
<action name="login" class="com.hussi.action.LoginAction">
    <result name="SUCCESS">/success.jsp</result>
    <result name="failure">/failure.jsp</result>
</action>
<action name="failure" class="com.hussi.action.LoginAction" method="foo">
    <result type="redirectAction">login.action</result>
</action>
```

But in the end, it's not clear at all if you have a `failure.jsp` result for your login action, why you should have a `failure action` returning the login action, or the login results. Try defining clearly what you need, and avoid custom, camouflaged results.

Comment: Have you tried ? If it worked, please remember accepting and upvoting, thanks